# Swift: Having issues uploading videos to firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload video files from my ios app to firebase but I get this error message:

2020-07-01 10:46:22.734237+0100 AppName[17646:835206] [core] "Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 (null)
2020-07-01 10:46:28.031932+0100 AppName[17646:835206] Task <568D30E0-41B3-4ADC-BC14-0E85365B1BAC>.<1> finished with error [-1] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1 "unknown error"
NOT WORKING

```
func convertAssestsToImages() -> Void {
    if selectedAssets.count != 0{
        for i in 0..<selectedAssets.count{
            let manger = PHImageManager.default()
            let optionB = PHVideoRequestOptions()
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            let pictureID = randomString(length: 12)
            let video_name = "Video\(pictureID)"
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
           
            optionB.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
        
            manger.requestAVAsset(forVideo: selectedAssets[i], options: optionB) { (asset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [AnyHashable : Any]?) -> Void in
                
                if let urlAsset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
                    //***video upload***
                    let localVideoUrl: URL = urlAsset.url as URL
                    let storeVideo = storageRef.child("NAME1").child(SUB_NAME).child(video_name)
                    let metaData = StorageMetadata()
                    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
                    
                    storeVideo.putFile(from: localVideoUrl, metadata: metaData) { (metaData, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            print("NOT WORKING")
                        }else{
                            print("WORKING")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is StorageMetadata?

Comment: I would write the selected asset to a sandboxed folder at first.

Comment: @ElTomato Thanks for your response, have updated the "StorageMetadata" but that's not where the error is coming from.